# Dynamic Invoice Forms fields and posting to a database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am building a form to create invoices. At the moment it has the form fields of:

Product Name, QTY.

I have a "add more" button which adds another row of the above form fields.

It then submits as an array to another php page. What i am having problems with is matching each associated form field with each other because when i save it in the database i need the correct Product Name, QTY to be on the same row in the table obviously. Just not sure how to match them.

Currently my code on the form field page is:

```
<html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Invoice Test</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  

           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <div class="container">  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <h2 align="center">Invoice Test</h2>  
                <div class="form-group">  
                     <form name="submit" id="submit" action="name.php" method="POST">  
                          <div class="table-responsive">  
                               <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
                                    <tr>  
                                         <td><input type="text" name="product_name[]" placeholder="Product Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td>  
                                         <td><input type="text" name="qty[]" placeholder="QTY" class="form-control name_list" /></td>  
                                         <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>  
                                    </tr>  
                               </table>  
                               <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />  
                          </div>  
                     </form>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="product_name[]" placeholder="Product Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><input type="text" name="qty[]" placeholder="QTY" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });  
 });  
 </script>
```

On the name.php page where the form submits to. What is the best way to get each product and associated qty from the array and put them into the database row. Keeping in mind this is dynamic.

On name.php when i print out $_POST i currently have this array structure:

```
Array
(
    [product_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => test1
            [1] => test2
            [2] => test3
            [3] => test4
        )

    [qty] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )

    [submit] => Submit
)
```

Im guessing I need to count the keys and then match them in the other dimension of the array. Just not sure if that is the best way or even how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this

```
$productName = $_POST['productName'];
$qty = $_POST['qty']

foreach($productName as $key => $productName) {
  $productQty = $qty[$key];

  //Use your ORM (or whatever) to inster into DB
  //$productName and $productQty

}
```

**EDIT**

Or, even better, you could user PHP's `array_combine`:

```
$productName = $_POST['productName'];
$qty = $_POST['qty']

$arryWithTotals  = array_combine($productName, $qty);

foreach($arrayWithTotals as $productName => $productQty) {
  //insert into DB
}
```

Comment: My god. I went looking for something that did this in the php manual. Must have overlooked it. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer. That is exactly what i needed and very easy to implement.

I will accept the answer shortly when it lets me.

Comment: i had to change it as i ended up with 4 form fields and there for 4 arrays. I have a new problem. If you put a number in the fields single price and then qty you will notice the total price field and the tax fields update with required maths outputs.

The problem im having is it wont do any others that are added except for the one that was there originally. im not sure how to make it do that maths on dynamic form fields added: http://pastebin.com/3pH3CX88

Answer (score 0):

```
If you wish you can use like these way.
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Invoice Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <br />
    <br />
    <h2 align="center">Invoice Test</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
        <form name="submit" id="submit" action="name.php" method="POST">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php
                            session_start();

                            if (isset($_SESSION["message"]) && !empty($_SESSION["message"])) {
                                echo $_SESSION["message"];
                                unset($_SESSION["message"]);
                            }

                            ?></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="product_name[]" placeholder="Product Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="qty[]" placeholder="QTY" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                        <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var i=1;
        $('#add').click(function(){
            i++;
            $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="product_name[]" placeholder="Product Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><input type="text" name="qty[]" placeholder="QTY" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
        });
        $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
            var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
            $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
PHP
====

$data = $_POST['product_name'];
$data2 = $_POST['qty'];

$product_name = "'" . implode("','", array_values($data)) . "'";
$qty = "'" . implode("','", array_values($data2)) . "'";

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("unable to connect Mysql");
mysql_select_db("Your DB Name called here") or die("unable to connect DB");

$query = "INSERT INTO `Your DB Name called here`.`Your Table Name called here` (`id`, `product_name`,`qty` ) VALUES (NULL, '$product_name', '$qty')";
if (mysql_query($query)) {
    $_SESSION["message"] = "Successfully submitted";
}
header("location:your page name.php");
```